# Cloudfront API Distribution Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to retrieve the status of my Cloudfront distributions through boto3 but it seems like the status returned through get_distribution or list_distributions only returns the state instead (Deployed or in-progress).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUwQK.png)

{
"ResponseMetadata":{
"RequestId":"bacc7917-90b4-4f91-8915-5dc7201b179a",
"HTTPStatusCode":200,
"HTTPHeaders":{
"x-amzn-requestid":"bacc7917-90b4-4f91-8915-5dc7201b179a",
"etag":"ECIVXNE16EKWC",
"content-type":"text/xml",
"content-length":"3102",
"date":"Thu 02 Feb 2023 21:33:47 GMT"
},
"RetryAttempts":0
},
"ETag":"ECIVXNE16EKWC",
"Distribution":{
"Id":"E2H2PR2OHJ17TC",
"ARN":"arn:aws:cloudfront::556730911179:distribution/E2H2PR2OHJ17TC",
**"Status":"Deployed"**,
"LastModifiedTime":"datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 2, 21, 29, 35, 959000, tzinfo=tzutc())",
"InProgressInvalidationBatches":0,
"DomainName":"dx4o38vn878h1.cloudfront.net",
"ActiveTrustedSigners":{
"Enabled":false,
"Quantity":0

Anyone know a way to return the status (enabled / disabled) of a cloudfront distribution through boto3 ?

I tried returning the output through get_distribution and list_distributions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.get_distribution_config) & [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_GetDistributionConfig.html) for config mentions 'Enabled' field but also says it is to enable/disable the distribution. Might worth to try inspecting `get_distribution_config` to see if Enabled is coming back in the results.

Comment: Found it ! Withing the distribution config you indeed have the field. Thank you !